# Despues de mandar un paquete UDP el listener no detecta mas (NetCat)

Tags: linux, bash, redes

tengo el sigueinte problema

En la maquina B (192.168.200.4)
ejecuto ````` nc -u -l 9999```` y en la maquina A (192.168.200.3) ejecuto ````` echo "hola" | nc -u -w1 192.168.200.4 9999````

Seguidamente , B recibe el "Hola" de A, pero si luego (con B aun escuchando), vuelvo a ejecutar el comando, A no recibe nada (ni vuelve a recibir).

**Mi objectivo es que B siga escuchando y poder mandar ese "hola" las veces que quiera y ser recibido**

**EDICION 1**

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
        nc -w 5 -l -u -p 9999  
done
```

He probado a hacer segun los comentarios pero , ahora no recibe nada de A,
y pues cada 5 segundo ,manda un "no connection : Connection timed out"

Comment: De entrada, UDP no garantiza que todos los paquetes lleguen a su destino.

Comment: No tiene que ver con el problema a mano. Cuando le llega el mensaje del cliente, el proceso que estaba escuchando deja de escuchar. Acabo de hacer unas pruebas en mi equipo y a lo que u cliente se conecta, el servidor cierra el puerto por el que estaba escuchando. Como no hay nada para controlar la sesion, el servidor ni se entera de que del lado del cliente el proceso ya murió. Deberías considerar usar un timeout del lado del servidor para que luego de unos segundos el proceso cierre y si estás en un ciclo infinito, vas a volver a entrar a escuchar mas conexiones al arrancar otro proceso.

Comment: podrías considerar también escribir tu propio servidor para que escuche ad infinitum

Comment: por favor revisen mi ultima edicion de la pregunta

Comment: en el servidor (la maquina B) puedes usar el flag "-k" si lo tiene, creo que vuelve a escuchar despues de que termina una conexión

Comment: Perfecto, gracias a todos y a ti @braver , la opcion -k fue la que me ha arreglado el problema

Comment: La solución va en la zona de respuestas y no en la pregunta, quitala de aquí y muévela donde corresponde por favor

Answer (score 1):

Utilizar la opcion -k de NetCat en el servidor

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
        nc  -l -k -u -p 9999  
done
```

Gracias a braver y eftshift0.